# Excel VBA - Creating a Table In a Specific Non-Default(A1) Location

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016, listobject

If you run the following code:

```
WorkSheet.ListObjects.add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Destination:=Range("A10:C13"))
```

One might be tempted into thinking, this would place table in the range of "A10:C13". It does not, a table is instead inserted into A1 with one column and one row(excluding the header):

[image]

This is clearly specified in the [Official Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823155.aspx) of this function:

> The Destination argument is ignored if SourceType is set to
>   xlSrcRange.

How do you insert a table into any other range of cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding your worksheet range definition into the wrong parameter.

```
WorkSheet.ListObjects.add SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=WorkSheet.Range("A10:C13")
```

See [ListObjects.Add Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823155.aspx) for a full description of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Using the documentation provided from [this page](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html), I simulated what a user might do to add a table:

```
Range("A10:C13").Select
WorkSheet.ListObjects.add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange)
```

It seems adding the select statement will place the table into the correct location.

Comment: One of the very few times in VBA where `.Select` is actually useful!

Comment: Useful perhaps, but not absolutely necessary.